# List sent over AJAX and compared to seemingly identical list in Django returns false

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

So I have an AJAX function that compiles a list like so:

```
var message_pk_list = $('.message-panel').not('.example').map(function(){return $(this).data('pk');}).get();
```

It is then sent to my django server via AJAX with datatype json.

When it gets there, I have this function that handles it:

```
def ajax_enquiry_check(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        old_message_pk_list = map(int, request.POST.getlist('message_pk_list[]'))
        """ Some stuff here to find enquiry"""
        new_message_pk_list = Message.objects.filter(enquiry=enquiry).order_by('-sent_at').values_list('pk', flat=True)
        print old_message_pk_list
        print new_message_pk_list
        print old_message_pk_list == new_message_pk_list
```

Output from console is:

```
[62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57]
[62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57]
False
```

In what way are they not equal?

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered answer immediately after posting.

values_list(flat=True) does not return a list, it returns a [ValuesListQuerySet.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list)

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the OP's own answer, The above behaviour is happening because `old_message_pk_list` and `new_message_pk_list` are of different types.

We can do a little inspection in shell.

```
In [1]: type(old_message_pk_list)
Out[1]: list

In [2]: type(new_message_pk_list)
Out[2]: django.db.models.query.ValuesListQuerySet

In [3]: isinstance(new_message_pk_list, list) # can see that its not a list type
Out[3]: False

In [4]: old_message_pk_list == new_message_pk_list
Out[4]: False
```

Though `it appears that old_message_pk_list` and `new_message_pk_list` having the same number of elements and same corresponding elements must be equal, but `new_message_pk_list` not being actually a list leads to `False` when comparing them.